# We need to write the object in the database MySQL, how to do?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'user_records'
});

async function getUsers(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json();
    const usersID = result.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const { id, name, username, email, address, phone } = item;
        acc.push([id, name, username,
            email, address.city, phone]);
        return acc
    }, [])
    console.log(usersID);
}

        db.connect(async (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error occurred..', err)
    } else {
        console.log('MySQL Connected...')
        let values = await getUsers(url);
        let query = `INSERT INTO user_records.users (id, name, username, email, city, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;
        db.query(query, [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("Insert to DB" + result.rowsAffected)
            }
        })
    }
});
```

> I take the json api from the site using the getUsers(url) asynchronous method, and I also take the data I need such as id, name username email, adress.city, phone and put them in an array

[
1,
'Leanne Graham',
'Bret',
'Sincere@april.biz',
'Gwenborough',
'1-770-736-8031 x56442'
]

Then I try to write the data to the database, but it does not work,
typeof values - object
typeof query - string
More tested the database if after values (here to write the data is written to the database)

Comment: Serialize or json encode your object values

Comment: Thank you all for solving the problem, the function did not return a usersID